# Lucene: building an index

Tags: java, lucene

I've built a project long time ago using Lucene 4.6. Now currently want to upgrade to 7.3.

This project has three files with one class each (with the same name as the file): Main, Indexer, Search.

I'm getting a problem in the *Indexer.java*, more specifically in *buildIndex()*.

Inside of *Main.java* i have defined the place with the data directory and where the index is going to be and started creating the index by sending the path to *buildIndex()* where it must be built:

```
File dataDirectory = new File("C:\\datalocation");
File indexDirectory = new File("C:\\indexlocation");
(...)

IndexWriter index = Indexer.createIndex(indexDirectory);
Indexer.buildIndex(index, dataDirectory, indexDirectory);
Indexer.closeIndex(index);
System.out.println("Index built");
```

Inside of *Indexer.java*:

```
static void buildIndex(IndexWriter index, File dataDirectory,
            File IndexDirectory) throws IOException {
        File[] files = dataDirectory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Document document = new Document();

            Reader reader = new FileReader(files[i]);
//the following line is where error 1 appears:
            document.add(new Field("contents", reader));

            String path = files[i].getCanonicalPath();
//the following line is where error 2 appears:
            document.add(new Field("path", path, Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

            index.addDocument(document);
        }
    }
```

The problems I get are:

1. > The constructor Field(String, Reader) is undefined.
2. > Index cannot be resolved or is not a field

**How can I fix this?**

Cast argument 'reader' to 'IndexableFieldType'

OR

Change type of 'reader' to 'IndexableFieldType' are not an option.

*To note:* The data directory path has in there a .txt file just with "Maven" written in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these constructors of `Field` are marked as [deprecated](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#Field(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader)) in Lucene 4, and were removed later on.

The recommended classes are [TextField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) in both cases, or also [StringField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) for the second one.

So the first one could look like :

```
document.add(new TextField("contents", reader));
```

And the second one :

```
document.add(new StringField("path", path, Field.Store.YES));
```

Note that I couldn't find a clear equivalent of the `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED` parameter, though (`StringField` is not tokenized, `TextField` is, don't know if it is directly related to this).